# QuTip: How to multiply symbol with matrix

Tags: sympy, qutip

I am trying to multiply a symbol with a matrix which is defined by `QuTip quantum object`, but I got this error:

```
TypeError: Incompatible object for multiplication
```

I used:

```
from qutip import *
import sympy as sp
w0 = sp.Symbol('\omega_{0}')
w0*destroy(4)
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: this doesn't work because `qutip.destroy(4)` gives a `qutip.Qobj` object, and there is no defined multiplication operation between those and `sympy` objects. At least up to 2018, there was no straightforward way to achieve what you want, see https://groups.google.com/g/qutip/c/Op7QBNNgpYc?pli=1. Depending on what the overall goal is, you might be better served by defining a function taking `w0` as input and returning `w0 * qutip.destroy(4)` (so that when the function is used, `w0` is a number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object `destroy(4)` contains a lot more information than just the matrix representation of the annihilation operator, so its represented as the type `Qobj` in qutip. The type `Qobj` currently doesn't support multiplication with the type `sympy.Symbol`. Note that you can look under the `__rmul__` method of `Qobj` to find which types are supported for multiplying with `Qobj` on the right.

If you're happy working with the matrix representations of these operators you could do the following to multiply a symbol with the matrix corresponding to `destroy(4)`. The following will work:

```
w0 * destroy(4).data.todense()
```

This will be a numpy matrix containing symbols, and you can multiply it with the matrices corresponding to other operators in your calculation (at a great loss of efficiency!).

Otherwise this might be worth posting an issue on their github. An implementation might be possible based on how `__rmul__` is dispatched to `numbers.Number` [here](https://github.com/qutip/qutip/blob/b71625e004b9d99b0c2b4f777c1937d299de08e5/qutip/qobj.py#L603).